# Format a number into a datatable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Format a table in JavaScript. I have 1 table with the following data CUNIT: .056 What I want: 0.056 In my database my procedure gives me a result of 0.056. Use the DataTables | Table plugin for jQuery. What I want to do is in the image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAI6x.png)

```js
var tbl_ctsunit;
function List_CTSUnit(id){
    tbl_ctsunitario = $("#tbl_ctsunit").DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "searching": {"regex":false},
        "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100,-1],[10,25,50,100, "All"]],
        "pageLength":10,
        "destroy": true,
        "async": false,
        "processing": true,
        "bPaginate":false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo":false,
        "sDom":'t',
        "ajax":{
            "url": "../controller/datos/controller_list_ctsunit.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                id:id
            }
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"PRODUC"},
            {"data":"T_UNIT"},
            {"data":"CUNIT"},
        ],
        "language":idioma_espanol,
        select: true
    });
}
```

```html
<table id="tabla_ctsunitario" class="display">
<thead>
<label>Costos Unitario</label>
<tr>
<th>PROD</th>
<th style="width:100px">CUNIT</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: _"What is the `document.getElementById('txtunit').value = Number(data0).toFixed(3)` does not work here."_ - what are you talking about here? That line is nowhere to be found in the code you have shown, and neither is any element with an ID `txtunit` to begin with.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628102/how-to-add-leading-zeros-in-datatable-data) adds leading zeros, which you could reuse, but seems there should be a simpler way for formatting number.   Is `CUNIT` actually a *number* or is it a string?

Comment: I suspect you just need to set the column type correctly (at the moment it's inferred).  See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type  change `{"data":"CUNIT"},` to `{"data":"CUNIT", "type":"num"},`

Comment: change {"data":"CUNIT"} with {"data":"CUNIT","type":"num"}, and it doesn't work